# How to turn a line in a file into a 2d array

Tags: python, arrays, magic-square

I'm fairly new to python and I've been struggling with coding a program that will take a line in a file as input to verify a Lo Shu Magic Square. What i need to do is read one line in the file at a time and with each line 
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
for instance, and convert that into a 2d array like 
[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
The first three numbers correspond to the values in the first row of the magic square, the next three values correspond to the second row, and the last three values correspond to the last row.

So far I've tried

```
def main():
  data = []
  for line in open('Magic Square Input.txt'):
    items = line.split(" ")
    temp = 0
    setOfThree = []
    for item in items:

        if(len(item) > 1):
            item = item[0:1]

        if(item != " "):
            setOfThree.append(item)
            temp += 1


        if(temp == 3):
            test = []
            test = setOfThree[:]
            test = [int(x) for x in test]
            data.append(test)
```

But that only gives me

```
[[4, 3, 8]]
[[4, 3, 8], [8, 3, 4]]
[[4, 3, 8], [8, 3, 4], [6, 1, 8]]
[[4, 3, 8], [8, 3, 4], [6, 1, 8], [6, 9, 8]]
[[4, 3, 8], [8, 3, 4], [6, 1, 8], [6, 9, 8], [6, 1, 8]]
[[4, 3, 8], [8, 3, 4], [6, 1, 8], [6, 9, 8], [6, 1, 8], [6, 1, 3]]
[[4, 3, 8], [8, 3, 4], [6, 1, 8], [6, 9, 8], [6, 1, 8], [6, 1, 3], [5, 5, 5]]
```

The contents of the text file are

```
4 3 8 9 5 1 2 7 6
8 3 4 1 5 9 6 7 2
6 1 8 7 5 3 2 9 4
6 9 8 7 5 3 2 1 4
6 1 8 7 5 3 2 1 4
6 1 3 2 9 4 8 7 5
5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5
```

So I feel like im on the right track, but its only appending the first three items of each line to data and i cant figure out why

Comment: What have you attempted, and what exactly are you struggling with? Editing your question so we can see your code so far and detailing what is going wrong will greatly increase your chances of getting a good answer.

Comment: The program needs to be able to take this 2d array, verify it as being a valid magic square or not, then print valid or invalid for each line given if its a magic square or not

Comment: That doesn't address my question - I asked what you have tried, and what is going wrong. Stack Overflow isn't a code writing service, and you're not going to get your entire program done for you.

Comment: I hadn't had the chance to edit it for you,  and im new to this site so i didnt know how to word my question exactly

Comment: Thank you for editing! It is much better now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lines have always 9 elements so

```
line = "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9"

items = line.split()

result = [items[0:3], items[3:6], items[6:9]]

print(result)
```

---

**EDIT:** the same with all lines

```
lines = """4 3 8 9 5 1 2 7 6
8 3 4 1 5 9 6 7 2
6 1 8 7 5 3 2 9 4
6 9 8 7 5 3 2 1 4
6 1 8 7 5 3 2 1 4
6 1 3 2 9 4 8 7 5
5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5"""

data = []

for line in lines.split('\n'):

    items = line.split()

    data.append([items[0:3], items[3:6], items[6:9]])

print(data)
```

---

If you need more universal - for different `N`

```
N = 3

data = []

for line in lines.split('\n'):

    items = line.split()
    array = []

    while items:
        array.append(items[:N])
        items = items[N:]

    data.append(array)

print(data)
```